# Error program.asm(8): error A2070: invalid instruction operands

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I want to swap to 8 bit variables var1 and var2, using registers, but it give me this error. What is wrong with this code?

```
include irvine32.inc

.data

var1 byte 20

var2 byte 30

.code 

main proc

mov al,var2

mov var2,var1

mov var1,al

call dumpregs

exit 

main endp

end main
```

Comment: You can't move memory to memory in one `mov` instruction. This is a problem `mov var2,var1` . You can move memory to a temporary register and then from that register to another memory location.

Answer (score 2):

Memory to memory operation are not allowed, you can use this code:

```
mov al,var1

mov ah,var2

mov var1,ah

mov var2,al
```

Comment: You don't need XCHG, just store AH to var1 and AL to var2.

Comment: You are right, it was an unnecessary operation, I edited the solution.